# Jenkins Git API

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jgit

We are currently developing custom Jenkins plugin. We need to do some operations with the git repository. We are interested in the history of the repository (for example: Commit messages, tag messages, etc.). I want to ask if there is some Java Jenkins Git Api, that can read this informations from the repository. For now we found out that JGit is able to do it, but we are not sure how it will work with the Jenkins instance running on the server. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Jenkins itself does not have git integration, git is enabled via the git plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) - you would be best viewing the documentation for that to see if it has an API. This plugin uses Jenkins SCM API (https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-api) to interface with Jenkins itself. I believe the SCM API plugin ships with Jenkins 'out of the box'.

Answer (score 0):

Try [scm4j-vcs-git](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-git):

```
public static final String WORKSPACE_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "git-workspaces";
...
IVCSWorkspace workspace = new VCSWorkspace(WORKSPACE_DIR);
String repoUrl = "https://github.com/MyUser/MyRepo";
IVCSRepositoryWorkspace repoWorkspace = workspace.getVCSRepositoryWorkspace(repoUrl);
IVCS vcs = new GitVCS(repoWorkspace);
vcs.setCredentials("user", "password"); // if necessary
vcs.getBranchesList();
vcs.getCommitMessages(...); //see doc
//etc
```

The project is currently developing, so you can request features you need.